# Apply Image height to Div on resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider inside a div. However slider's relative positions makes the slider to go below the container div. I thought of increasing the height of div by getting the height of the slider image and adding it to the class/id of the respective div.

```
var img = $("#gallery > img");
$("#gallery").css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
```

HTML CONTENT

```
 <div id="gallery">

  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/shom/gallery/birdsview.jpg"/>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/shom/gallery/living.jpg"/>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/shom/gallery/bedroom.jpg"/>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12>Some description here</div>
```

CSS PART

```
#gallery { position: relative; }
#gallery > img { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display: none; }
#gallery > img:first-child { display: block; }
```

Above you can see the script I used. But the issue is when I resize the browser window, the height is not adapting accordingly. It still applies the height, when the page was loaded initially.

Looking forward for your support on this.

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS otherwise is not simple for us to say why the below div stay on top of the container.

Comment: Apologies. I have now updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The perfect solution to handle such a situation is to handle with css, because if you have a slider inside a container, the container is supposed to grow at least as much as its contents unless it has a fixed height.

How ever now, you can fix this issue by running the script again while the window resizes,

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var img = $("#gallery > img");
  $("#gallery").css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
});
```

The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes.

Comment: I ran your script. But seems its not taking the height or width. Are we missing something. Please suggest.

Comment: I tried the CSS options, but failed. So thought of applying height to the container div through script

Comment: I tried a jsfiddle of the script and the window resize works, it fires the event. Try adding a console.log inside and see whether its being fired